# update reference is not updating the view on an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested ng-repeat on a var 
`$scope.delivery` with a nested object `orders`
`ng-repeat="order in delivery.orders"`

If I change the object directly the view is been updated.

```
$scope.delivery.orders[0] = [];
```

if I try to use a reference

```
var ref = $scope.delivery.orders[0];
ref = [];
```

The view is not been updated.
Also I trace that the $scope.delivery.orders[0] values is not been updated.

Comment: Might be the case that angular digest cycle listen to just scope variable try to cal scope apply manually

Comment: use `$watch` hope it will work. Or post a fiddle

Comment: I dont think emptying reference wont affect the source.Can you use `splice` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$watch`

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('controller',function($scope){
  $scope.delivery = {
  'orders': [1,2,3,4,5]
  };
  $scope.click = function(){
    $scope.ref = $scope.delivery.orders;
    $scope.ref[0] = 9;
    $scope.$watch($scope.ref, function(){
    $scope.delivery.orders = $scope.ref ;
    })
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
<ul><li ng-repeat="order in delivery.orders">{{order}}
</li></ul>
<button ng-click="click()">click</button>
</div>
```